# Externalizing configuration in Spring Boot with multiple applications running in the same container

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, war

I'm building multiple Spring Boot applications which will be deployed on the same servlet container. But I'm having difficulties getting Spring Boot to work with externalized configuration files the way I want, and not like the framework wants.

**Situation:**

- multiple Spring Boot applications will be deployed on a single servlet container (WAR file)
- the location of configuration files will be set via JVM property `spring.config.location`
- embedded deployment is not an option

**Problem:**

As the  applications are deployed on the same JVM, the property `spring.config.location` has the same value for all applications. I want our applications to all use the same configuration file naming (application.properties), so specifying `spring.config.name` is not an option.

**What I would like:**

- no need to set `spring.config.name` as the configuration name should be standardized accross all our applications (constant)
- the externalized configuration properties should override values from application.properties packaged inside my deployed WAR
- profile specific configurations (application-{profile}) should be possible
- no hardcoded config locations in code
- organizing configuration files in a per-application directory layout:

  ${spring.config.location}/app1/application.properties
  ${spring.config.location}/app2/application.properties
  ${spring.config.location}/app3/application.properties

**Questions:**

Is there some mechanism to influence or override loading or resolving of external configuration files?

Are there other approaches to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestions of @Iulian Rosca to use a pattern like `${properties_home}/${application_id}/application.properties` brought me to the idea of defining a custom JVM property like `app.config.root` and using this property to override `spring.config.location` very early in the application lifecycle.

My application class looks now like this and works for embedded and container deployments:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return configureApplication(builder);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        configureApplication(new SpringApplicationBuilder()).run(args);
    }

    private static SpringApplicationBuilder configureApplication(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder
            .sources(Application.class)
            .properties("spring.config.location:${${app.config.root}/myapp1/:#{null}}");
    }

}
```

Important notes to this solution:

- `app.config.root` has to be set externally by JVM or JNDI property
- `app.config.root` can only contain a single external configuration path (for my requirements this was sufficient) in contrast to `spring.config.location` where multiple comma-separated paths can be specified
- `SpringApplicationBuilder.properties(...)` sets the application's default properties. Because of this, `spring.config.location` cannot be specified externally anymore, as JVM or JNDI Properties have priority over default properties and would therefore override `spring.config.location` again.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve what you're trying by using `@PropertySource`. According to the official documentation ([Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config)) you can use this annotation to externalize configuration files, e.g.:

```
 @Configuration
 @PropertySource("file:/path/to/application.properties")
 public class AppConfig {

 }
```

As stated in [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html), inside `@PropertySource` you can use placeholders that would be resolved against other property sources, for e.g. values declared in `application.properties`

> Assuming that "my.placeholder" is present in one of the property sources already registered, e.g. system properties or environment variables, the placeholder will be resolved to the corresponding value. If not, then "default/path" will be used as a default. Expressing a default value (delimited by colon ":") is optional. If no default is specified and a property cannot be resolved, an IllegalArgumentException will be thrown.

You can declare `properties_home` as an environment variable and `application_id` inside your `application.properties` file.

```
 @Configuration
 @PropertySource("${properties_home}/${application_id}/application.properties")
 public class AppConfig {

 }
```

Don't forget to enable support for resolving the placeholders:

> In order to resolve ${...} placeholders in bean definitions or @Value annotations using properties from a PropertySource, one must register a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer. This happens automatically when using  in XML, but must be explicitly registered using a static @Bean method when using @Configuration classes.

**Update:**

In order to override the properties from the external file you could use a spring profile. Inside the packaged application.properties you need to set:

```
spring.profiles.active=external
```

Declare all the properties that you want to take precedence as part of the external profile inside the file located in `"${properties_home}/${application_id}/application.properties"`.

Comment: I like the approach of using placeholders as the property source value.
But there are several limitations: I can't use the additional sugar that Spring Boot does with configuration files, like profile suffixes or different configuration formats (properties, yml). Another problem is that @PropertySource doesn't actually override my default values that I specified in application.properties inside the packaged WAR file. This seems to be the case, because according to the documentation, PropertySources are below application configuration files in the priority chain.

Comment: 1. Can you elaborate what does the following statement mean "I can't use the additional sugar that Spring Boot does with configuration files, like profile suffixes or different configuration formats (properties, yml)". 2 You didn't specify in the original question that you want to override values in the packaged application.properties.

Comment: 1. What I tried to say is, that Spring Boot by default doesn't only find a file "application.properties" but also the files "application-{profile}.properties" or "application.yml".
2. Yes, my bad. I forgot to mention it, since I thought this was the most common use case for externalized configuration.

Comment: I have updated my response to achieve (2). This is only one way of doing it, others are via JNDI, ServletContext, etc. see the full list in the documentation. Using spring profiles is the easiest way. It is still not clear what you are trying to say with (1) or with the updated details in the original question - "profile specific configurations (application-{profile}) should be possible".