# can we have single application.properties file for multiple microservices in spring-boot framework?

Tags: spring-boot, openshift, microservices

Is it feasible to have only one application.properties for microservices built in spring-boot and deployed on openshift?

Comment: Possibly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44144118/externalizing-configuration-in-spring-boot-with-multiple-applications-running-in

Comment: I believe you could also have your application properties in a dependency that you pull into your micro services and then have it available via that

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring cloud config service to have a common properties file for common properties between microservices, you can arrange your configuration this way:

```
src/main/resources/
    bootstrap.yml
    application.yml
    service1.yml
    service2.yml
```

Where application.yml in each profile folder will have default configurations for each service which can be overridden in configuration file of that service.